# How to create LaunchImage Using iOS 9 with Xcode 7.1.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I am hardly trying to create `LaunchImage` using `Launch Screen storyboard` with proper `Assets` but I am getting only white screens. Below I have explained about What I did into my source

**`STEP 1:`** I have created below `sizes of images` with proper name for `iPhone launch screen`

```
Default.png   :  320 * 480
Default@2x.png   :  640 * 960 
Default-568h@2x.png   :  640 * 1136 
Default-375w-667h@2x~iphone.png   :  750 * 1134  (iPhone 6)
Default-414w-736h@3x~iphone.png   :  1242 * 2208 (iPhone 6 plus)
```

**`STEP 2:`** I have added `New iOS LaunchImage` Into `assets` and enabled all the `versions` only portrait `(iOS6 to iOS 9)` and drag and drop all the Images on proper place.

**`STEP 3`:** In `Xcode 7.1.1` default we can get `Launch Screen.storyboard` with `Viewcontroller` of `View`. I have added `UIImageView` and set the proper `constraints` for full screen. For this ImageView I set `"Aspect Fit"`.

**`STEP 4:`** Now I have checked into my `Info.plist` at Launch screen interface file base name.

Now If I run my application I am getting White screen. I know I did some mistakes. Please give me a right solution. What I missed above steps from correct way!

```
Development Version 

iOS 6 to 9
Xcode 7.1.1
```

Comment: what did u give to the image view ?

Comment: Image view I cant get any reffernce for Images. I dont know exactly the proper way of launchScreen. Please give me a proper steps. I am having above size of images, now what i want to do?@Mr.T

Comment: did u try giving the image name to image view in xcode ?

Comment: Yes I have tired but this is the first time for lunch screen within storyboard. Actually which one is proper way of lunchscreen process? and I cant add .xib into Xcode 7.1.1. Please give me a solution.

Comment: by the way what constraints did u put ?

Comment: UIImageview all 4 edges putted the constants to 0. Its showing full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not select the assets for the Launch Screen Image.

After you drag and drop all the images into the launch screen file,go to the project general settings:

And click on launch images source option and select Don't use asset catalogs
 [image]

After you select this option, it should look like this:

[image]

And Make sure you have the name for the asset as **LaunchImage**

You need to put the image in the assets folder:
[image]

and you need to mention the image for the image view in the attributes insepctor:
[image]

You can follow the steps mentioned [here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios8-day-by-day-day-27-launch-images) for more detailed explanation:

Comment: Above steps I did properly and cleaned my app still showing white screen @Mr.T

Comment: what constraints did u put ? There may be a chance of wrong constraints making the image view shrink or move away from the screen

Comment: UIImageview all 4 edges putted the constants to 0. Its showing full screen.@Mr.T

Comment: the image assets will be automatically using the right image based on the device orientation, But You need to specify the launch image in the attribute inspector

Comment: Ok I will try If Once I done, I will vote ur answer. Give me few min! Thank you so much Mr.T Dear!

Comment: Hi Mr.T, If I want to to create LaunchImage without imageview, how Can I create?

Comment: No you can't modify the launch screen programmatically!!! It has to be done through storyboard.

Comment: IF you don't want the native launch screen, you can modify your initial view controller as launch screen and do whatever you want in there!!!

Comment: I am asking Without ImageView concept , directly add the different size of Images into assets. That methode how can we do properly? I mean Scaling the existing approach!

Comment: I am ready to to remove Imageview.tel me plz That another method! @Mr.T

Comment: as far as i know, there is no other method!!!! if you come to know, you left me know!!